# 'react-native' 'run-android' fails, but the app run successfully from Android studio

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, react-native-cli

The app runs from Android studio without any issue, but using `react-native run-android` I get this error message:

> info JS server already running.
> info Installing the app...
> info Connecting to the development server...
> info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
> Starting: Intent { cmp=com.joinfilter.customer/.MainActivity }
> Error type 3
> Error: Activity class {com.joinfilter.customer/com.joinfilter.customer.MainActivity} does not exist.

I checked the applicationId and its the same in all the places in the android project.

Another remarks/issues:

- `cd android && ./gradlew clean` has no effect.
- and I don't see the build folder inside android:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a different activity on your app launch, like a splash screen, you can try this:

```
react-native run-android --main-activity .ui.SplashScreenActivity
```

*.ui.SplashScreenActivity* is the activity path

Comment: I do have an activity `android:name="com.joinfilter.customer.SplashActivity"`, I tried  the command you provided but the error persists.

Comment: Try: react-native run-android --main-activity .SplashActivity

Comment: still throwing the same error.